# Алгоритм для онлайн-записи

Tags: php, sql, алгоритм

Заказчик поставил цель: создать для салона красоты онлайн запись на какую то услугу. Т.е. ты должен выбрать услугу, затем выбрать дату и тебе будет предложено время для записи. На каждую услугу устанавливается какое-то время (например 40 минут).

Выглядит форма примерно так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос у меня в том, как сделать если все мастера заняты, то нельзя было записаться на это время (всего 5 мастеров) и самое главное они могут быть заняты до разного времени.
Уже 2 дня не могу придумать, какие есть идеи?

Спасибо!

Comment: Это от структуры вашей БД зависит. А ее вы не привели. Я бы генерил выпадающий список sql-запросом, который бы делал прямо эту сетку с часами и подклеивал к ней информацию о занятости мастеров (а так же их выходных, отпусках, больничных и т.п.). Ну и потом, при получении запроса на запись дополнительно проверял, что оно действительно свободно. Ну и длительность  сразу фиксировал в таблице занятого времени, беря его из справочника услуг. Правда потом надо еще продумать как будет выглядеть запись сразу на несколько услуг

Comment: хотя 40 мин в выпадающем списке это странно, может один из мастеров с 10:00 до 10:15 делал какую то короткую услугу и после уже свободен. значит надо просто позволять вводить время и во время ввода сразу проверять ajax занятость и выводить подсказки. Типа ввели 10 (часов) смотрим ближайшее свободное время и подсказываем 10:16 (но конечно не заставляем брать именно это время, может человеку удобно 10:30. Ну и уже заранее подумал бы о записи к конкретному мастеру (даже если заказчик об этом еще не думает, наверняка потом захочет, потому что у клиентов бывают предпочтения)